# Not able to read ngFor data in child component, getting property is not defined

Tags: typescript, angular6, components, ngfor

I am new to angular6,
I have a parent component in which i have a child component, I am using ngFor in parent component but not able to use the properties in component.

parent.ts :-

```
this.dummyDataService.getCardInfo().subscribe(
    data => { 
      this.cardInfo = data;
      console.log(this.cardInfo);
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done loading data')
);
```

parent.html:-

```
<card-tile class="grid-item grid-item" *ngFor="let item of cardInfo"></card-tile>
```

card-tile.html :-

```
    <li class="label-info" label="Enrolled On">{{item.enrolledOn}}</li>
    <li class="label-info" label="Contact">+91 {{item.contact}}</li>
    <li class="label-info" label="Consent">{{item.consent}}</li>
```

also tried with Elvis operator : -

```
{{item?.enrolledOn}}
```

error in console :  cannot read property enrolledOn of undefined

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `item` property of your `card-title.ts` class. Something like

```
<card-tile class="grid-item grid-item" *ngFor="let item of cardInfo" [item]="item"></card-tile>
```

should work.